# Import a directory of dbf files to sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to import `.dbf` files using for each container in `SSIS`. But i keep getting errors to map the files and other errors.

Here is what did.

1. Use for each container.
2. Use a data flow task in the container.
3. Use `OLE DB` source for Visual FoxPro (or `jet` ) and set extended properties as DBase IV and connection string as variable from expressions.
4. Use another variable for sql server table name, removing `.dbf` extension.
5. Use a `SQLOLEDB` destination and set its table as table, view or variable name. Set the variable to created one in step 4.

As the SQL Server table is not there already, how can I create and import dynamically. There are a lot of `.dbf` files so I am looking for dynamic creation of the same and import.